# Angular ng Translate non-breaking space &nbsp;

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

Hi is there any way to translate with non-breaking space `('&nbsp;')`
I have tried with this

```
 es.json:
    "&nbsp;example": "&nbsp;ejemplo";
    
In my component I have this:
<ex-component
description = "{{ ('&nbsp;example' | translate) }} >
```

but it is not working

Comment: Try using the unicode escaped value in json and js: `'\u00a0;example'`

Answer (score 7):

As Tătar pointed out in his comment, using \u00a0 will works, but please note that there is no semi-colon (;) at the end.